# Can CompleatableFuture be completed exceptionally in handle method?

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

I am trying to map the repository exception to the service exception. Is such an approach is good?

```
@Override
public CompletableFuture<Void> delete(String id, Map<String, String> headers) {
  CompletableFuture<Void> future = repository.delete(id, headers);
  return future.handle((aVoid, throwable) -> {
    if (throwable != null) {
      Throwable cause = throwable.getCause();
      if (DbExcUtils.isFKViolation(throwable)) {
        future.completeExceptionally(new BadRequestException(HAS_ASSIGNED_RECORDS_MESSAGE));
      } else {
        future.completeExceptionally(cause);
      }
    }
    return aVoid;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`handle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#handle(java.util.function.BiFunction)) will only invoke its given `BiFunction` when the target `CompletableFuture` instance is completed

> Returns a new `CompletionStage` that, **when this stage completes either
>   normally or exceptionally**, is executed with this stage's result and
>   exception as arguments to the supplied function.

In that sense, you can't complete it again. The javadoc for [`completeExceptionally`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completeExceptionally(java.lang.Throwable)) states

> **If not already completed**, causes invocations of `get()` and related
>   methods to throw the given exception.

It's essentially a no-op when the future is already completed.

If you just want to map the exception type, then use [`exceptionally`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#exceptionally(java.util.function.Function)).

> Returns a new `CompletionStage` that, when this stage completes
>   exceptionally, is executed with this stage's exception as the argument
>   to the supplied function. Otherwise, if this stage completes normally,
>   then the returned stage also completes normally with the same value.

which seems to do what you were attempting, ie. map the exception if there was one or, otherwise, return the result.

For example,

```
return future.exceptionally(throwable -> {
    Throwable cause = throwable.getCause();
    if (DbExcUtils.isFKViolation(throwable)) {
        throw new CompletionException(new BadRequestException(HAS_ASSIGNED_RECORDS_MESSAGE));
    } else {
        throw new CompletionException(cause);
    }
});
```

Note that we're throwing the new exception.

Also, you'll probably want to check if `throwable` is a `CancellationException` (without a cause) and rethrow it before you do your mapping logic.

---

You could use [`obtrudeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#obtrudeException(java.lang.Throwable)), but I don't recommend it

> Forcibly causes subsequent invocations of method `get()` and related
>   methods to throw the given exception, **whether or not already
>   completed**. This method is designed for use only in error recovery
>   actions, and even in such situations may result in ongoing dependent
>   completions using established versus overwritten outcomes.